# Check modelstate content in unit test .net core web api

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, nunit, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a simple controller with this action

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<MyModel>> PostAsync(CreationModel model)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Test error");

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    ...
}
```

With a unit test that looks a bit like this.

```
[Test]
public async Task Post_WhenCalled_BadRequest()
{
    var barRequestResult = (await controller.PostAsync(model)).Result as BadRequestObjectResult;

    Assert.That(barRequestResult, Is.TypeOf<BadRequestObjectResult>()); //This works
    Assert.That(barRequestResult.Value, //How can I test the content of modelstate????)
}
```

I can successfully test that the result is a BadRequest but how can I check the content of the modelstate?

Ta

Comment: Hi @Sun,Did my answer help you resolve your issue?

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check the content of the modelstate like below:

```
var data = barRequestResult.Value as Dictionary<string,object>;
var error = ((string[])data[""])[0];
Assert.That(true,error, "Test error");
```

Result:
[image]